# Pass parameters from commandline while executing protractor test

Tags: protractor

I want to execute the test where I can specify the browsername, environement name, suite name in execution command as follows
protractor conf.js browser=chrome env=staging suite=smoke

Is that possible with Jasmine and Protractor and
Can any one show me how to achieve that?

Answer (score 12):

To pass parameters to protractor, use `--params.cmdVar ="cmdVar"`

and again use it as above using `browser.params.cmdVar`

Answer (score 4):

Protractor has default feature where you are allowed to pass some parameters from command line. For e.g.

`protractor conf.js --baseUrl <UrlToTest> --suite <SuiteName>`

To pass some other project specific parameter, you can define that under params of config file.

`params: {
    env: 'someValue' 
}`

you can use:

`protractor conf.js --baseUrl <UrlToTest> --suite <SuiteName> --params.env <EnvValue>`

Comment: Thanks guys.. got it :)